# What is signer?

Tags: solidity, dapp-development

I am confused with the idea of signer.

1. What is signer?
2. What is use of it?
3. Why signer is important?
4. When we need to use signer?

Comment: at the level of source code, "signer" is a set of functions to sign transactions one way or another. For example, EIP155 introduced the ChainID field into transaction signature and now all transactions are signed using this field. So, every rule to sign a transaction is called a "signer" in Ethereum source code

Answer (score 0):

[Signer](https://docs.ethers.org/v5/api/signer/#:%7E:text=A%20Signer%20in%20ethers%20is,on%20the%20sub%2Dclass%20used.) signs a transaction with Signature, it is the fundamental of all blockchains.

Basically, every account on Blockchain has two keys. The public key and private key. The public key is exposed to everyone and the private key is known only to the user.

Any transaction on the blockchain should be attached with a signature. This signature is **generated** from the **private key**. Verifiers will use the sender's public key to "verify" if this transaction is indeed sent from the sender.

If the signature proves that this transaction is valid, the transaction is then included in the blocks.

For example:

A wants to send B 2 Eth. A need to:

1. create a transaction
2. sign the transaction
3. broadcast the transaction across blockchain nodes
4. a verifier picks up the transaction, verifies the signature, minds it into a block

If the signature doesn't match the transaction data and public key, this transaction is determined as fraudulent and discarded.

Hope that clarifies your doubt. Happy coding.

Comment: I m telling what did I understand: Singer is who **signs** a transaction in mark of acceptance the transaction. When A wants to transact he attaches a signature with the transaction, the signature is basically the hash of transaction data + private key. We can use this signature in **ecrecover** to get the address of A. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

a Signer is someone signing the transaction as a mark of acceptance towards the action of broadcasting that transaction to the rest of the network, it is the equivalent of you signing at the bank a paper with your signature.

It is the action of creating a new hash of the transaction by doing a mathematical operation between your private key and the original hash of the transaction.

As their names indicate it your private key is private, and your public key is public, the hash in question can only be deciphered by your public key.
Therefore anyone can verify with your public key if your private key signed a transaction